# Is there a way to globally unignore a file in projectile?

Tags: projectile

I have a few files that are ignored in most of the .gitignore project files, like .env and local-values.yaml.

Is there a way to not ignore them globally using projectile, so that I can find and open them with `projectile-find-file`?

Looks like a .projectile file would work, but sounds like it's per-project.